# Array of requests in Express or Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Can I get the array of requests, that handking at the moment, in Express or in Node.js itself?

I want to watch the number of requests on error and close the last with status 500.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, but for what I understand you might use a timeout and response `res.status(500).send('Timeout')`

Comment: @davidonet it's not a broblem to send 500 when I have the res object. But I want to handle the error in domain in the app's enter point where I have not the req and res objects.